# Is there a reason not to put a beefy cap on the output of a homemade power supply?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switching-regulator

I'm a beginner in electronics, and in the process of completing a homemade power supply would love to get some advice.

The power supply itself is fairly straightforward - I'm using a laptop power supply with an output of about 20V and it powers my circuit which consists of:

- 2 fixed at 3.3V and 5.0V
- 2 adjustable with voltage and current limit
- and another 5.0V to power an arduino nano
- 4 INA219 breakouts to measure each channel voltage and current
- an arduino nano to collect the data
- and an LCD to display voltages, currents, current limits, etc.

It all works, however, when I attach my homemade (arduino based) oscilloscope to the outputs, I'm noticing some ripple on the 3.3V and 5V channels, adding a 100uF cap improved it but didn't get rid of it, so I upped it to 1000uF which got the job done, (or at least within +-0.03V which is the margin of error of my crappy home-made oscilloscope).

So, the question is - is there any reason not to put a 1000uF cap at the outputs of these channels?

I don't have a schematic because the circuit was simple enough, so I didn't make one before implementing it.

To simplify my question further, imagine just a DC power source and a step-down switching voltage regulator, would there be any reason not to put a 1000uF capacitor on the output of the regulator?

EDIT: Added line breaks, I couldn't figure out how to do it last night. Sorry for the mess.

Comment: They didn't want to mess it up any more than it already is?

Comment: Wall of text...!! Don't you know how to create paragraphs?

Comment: Good for including full information about your question. But PLEASE learn to format it so that we can read it. Few people an read that much detail in such a huge "wall of text"!

Comment: There can be downsides - see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224421/is-there-any-downside-to-using-a-larger-than-needed-smoothing-capacitor for pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reasons against are

1. inrush current

   During startup, the capacitor effectively looks like a short to the power supply, so it will need to limit the current here.
2. "higher-than" requirements

   The +5V rail might need to be kept above the +3.3V rail all the time, even during startup and shutdown. If you add large output capacitors and the +5V rail drops faster during shutdown, then the +3.3V capacitors need to be discharged into the +5V rail to protect any dual-supply ICs. If you have a large capacitor, this needs to be a fairly beefy diode.

Answer (score 0):

If your DC/DC converters are current-limited, then inrush current isn't an issue.

Be sure they are stable with a large capacitor.